# Preventing dynamic sub nav from starting underneath its parent nav item

Tags: html, css

I'm building a progressive web app that outputs data onto the pages via an API. For example, there could be one page called about us and in about us could have history, location, etc... for its sub nav. Here are a couple of examples as to what I mean:

*When on the health & wellbeing page*
[image]
*When on the about us page*
[image]
The issue that I am having is because the about us links are contained in a UL element that is contained in the about us LI element, it positions the sub nav to start directly underneath it and not underneath where the logo is.

Here is the structure of the HTML code that populates the navigation, based on when visiting the about us page.

```
<ul>
  <li id="nav-1">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-2" class="open-two">
    <a href="/health-wellbeing">Health &amp; Wellbeing</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-13" class="open-two">
    <a href="/about-us">About Us<span><i class="arrow down"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="level-two" style="display: grid;">
      <li><a href="/about-us" class="current">About Us Home</a></li>
      <li id="nav-8">
        <a href="/history">History</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now I did try using `margin-left:-346px;` on the level-two UL element, which produced the following examples:

*When on the health & wellbeing page*
[image]
*When on the about us page*
[image]
Looks better on the health & wellbeing page, but then I realised after seeing the about us page that `margin-left:-346px;` didn't really fix the issue due to it only moving to the left a certain number of pixels.

So my question is, how do I get the dynamic sub nav to start underneath the logo and not start underneath its parent nav item so it turns out like the third image?

Update: Here is another example of what I am referring to https://jsfiddle.net/hkctdpqn/1/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to make the position of the parent UL element relative and make the position of the level-two UL element absolute. Then I adjusted the margin-left value until they all started underneath the logo and not to their parent elements.